# Is there any option to make getter expression shorter?

Tags: java

So i have a question about getter and setter. Let's see some code:

```java
class Object1 {
   private Object2 object2;
   public Object2 getObject2(){
      return this.object2;
   }
class Object2{
   private int a;
   public int getA(){
      return this.a;
   }
}

}
```

Is in Java language option to make expresions like this:
`object1.getObject2.getA()`
shorter? I know I have in this example very short, but what if, nesting will be more difficult? Is any pattern which solve my problem? Maybe i should refractor my code, to dont do such nests. Im so confused.

Comment: who says you can't add a getter for that Object2.a in Object1? public int getOA() { return this.getObject2.getA(); }

Comment: What is your question? There is no problem with this code. How would this code be more complicated if "nesting will be more difficult"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I ***think*** the question is about making `object1.getObject2.getA()` shorter. I think. :-)

Comment: @ Piotr - If I'm right that that's your question, no, there isn't a shorter way unless you change the API of `Object1` or `Object2`. In fact, it needs to be a *tad* bit longer because you're missing the `()` on `getObject2`: `object1.getObject2().getA()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, in `Object1` add a `getA()` and ***delegate*** to `object2`. Like,

```
public int getA(){
   return object2.getA();
}
```

Then you can use

```
object1.getA();
```

See also, the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Thank you very much :) You have just solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing in standard Java that lets you do this.

Project Lombok allows you to generate getters and setters without having them in source code, which can reduce the amount of boilerplate around POJOs.

But it sounds like you're specifically trying to avoid the following:

```
object1.getObject2().getObject3().getObject4();
```

There is no way to shorten this. This sort of code implies that there's a problem with your project's design, as it's a violation of the Law of Demeter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). This is a general rule as to how different layers of your code should interact with each other.

The above line of code is very much "ask, don't tell" - object 1 is requesting object 3 from object 2, and object 4 from object 3. The Law of Demeter inverts this into the pattern of "tell, don't ask". Using the analogy on the Wiki page, if you're walking a dog, you don't move the dog's legs yourself - you instead command the dog to move.

Comment: I have never heard about LoD, your post was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lombok Annotation here

```
@Data
class Object1 {
  private Object2 object2;

  @Data
  class Object2 {
    private int a;

  }

}
```

I have tired to access it in here

```
public class AccessObject1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object1 ob1=new Object1();
    ob1.getObject2();
    ob1.getObject2().getA();
  }

}
```